# Web Page Redirection Using Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, scripting, raspberry-pi2, forwarding

**Background**

I am doing Digital Signage using a raspberry Pi and most solutions allow you to only map 1 URL to the signage, but what i wanted to do is have it cycle through multiple pages on my local webserver.  The difficulty here is that we still need these pages to be intractable by normal users, as these will be for digital signage and for anyone on our local network to use.  I was originally thinking of just doing a meta refresh type redirection and cycle through the pages that way, but my last point makes that impractical for the normal user.

**Question**

Is there a way for me to map the Pi to a digital signage only page that could pop up full windowed pages for a set amount of time?  For example purposes there are 3 or more pages that i wanted to go through each for 30 seconds.  Without editing code on those webpages at all.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is create a mini single page app, where you will have a single URL and instead of changing the page, you change the view inside, that way all you need to do is render the new content inside the page instead of redirecting.
you can use anything from backbonejs to angularjs to reactjs and many more to achieve this.
it might be a little complicated for you and it might not based on the actual project you are trying to do.